# Need to click on a button in iFrame page

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on "btnPunch".  This button is located in an iFrame.  I am unable to make this work.  I have used the Selenium IDE to record this button being clicked and created a DLL that also runs this process in NUnit without a problem.  Any help would be appreciated after three months of working on this.
Thank you

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace TimeClockEntry
{
    public partial class PNow : Form
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        //driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        //private ISelenium selenium;
        //private StringBuilder verificationErrors;

        //public void SetupTest()
        //{
        //    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "https://ew23.ultipro.com/");
        //    selenium.Start();
        //    verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        //}

        int linkcount = 0;
        string userName;
        string passWord;

        public PNow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("https://ew23.ultipro.com/login.aspx");
        }

        private void PNow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

            userName = Properties.Settings.Default.userName;
            passWord = Properties.Settings.Default.passWord;
        }

        private void PNow_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            welcome f1 = new welcome();
            f1.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
        protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLostFocus(e);
            this.Focus();
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            linkcount++;

            if (linkcount == 1)
            {
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_Login1_UserName").SetAttribute("value", userName);
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_Login1_Password").SetAttribute("value", passWord);
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_Login1_LoginButton").InvokeMember("click");
            }

            if (linkcount == 2)
            {
                HtmlElement link = (from HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
                                    where elem.InnerHtml == "Time Clock Entry"
                                    select elem).ElementAt(0);
                link.InvokeMember("Click");
            }

            if (linkcount == 3)
            {
//                driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnPunch")).Click();
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_lnkLogout").InvokeMember("click");
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code where you tried to switch to the IFRAME. Where is that code? Did you google "selenium C# switch to iframe" and try anything? What did you try and what was the result?

Comment: I have tried Selenium.  Several times and several ways.  My bigest issue with selenium is that it wants to open a browser and not work within the confines of the webBrowser control.  I am fine with this, if I could get it to work consistently.  I can get it to work using NUnit but then I have to open a HTTP server.

Comment: I do apologize for not sending copies of all of my failed attempts.  I am not in the habit of keeping such information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if (linkcount == 3)
{
//get back to basic html source.
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
//switch to new frame
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("<FRAME NAME OR ID>");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnPunch")).Click();
}
```

Comment: Or in one line like: driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent().SwitchTo().Frame("<FRAME NAME OR ID>");

Comment: So, my question becomes... Should I stop trying to do this in a webBrowser control and just open a browser?

Comment: yes. i think it will be logically better to use one webDriver for doing all the job you need..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:-

```
if (linkcount == 3)
            {
                WebElement frameSwitch = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Xpath of iframe")); //Frame Xpath
                driver.switchTo().frame(frameSwitch);
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnPunch")).Click();
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_lnkLogout").InvokeMember("click");
                driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                this.Close();
            }
```